# VTK missing wbemidl.h

Tags: opencv, directx, vtk

I think this is related to directx.  The build is on a windows platform.  For now, I used the -k option on make to keep going, and hoping the unbuilt libraries are not needed by opencv.

Error message:

```
[ 54%] Building CXX object Rendering/OpenGL/CMakeFiles/vtkRenderingOpenGL.dir/vtkDirectXGPUInfoList.cxx.obj
C:\Software\VTK\VTK-6.3.0.rc1\Rendering\OpenGL\vtkDirectXGPUInfoList.cxx:27:21: fatal error: wbemidl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wbemidl.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are using Windows 10, it supports OpenGL2, so while configuration in CMake just turn the variable of : VTL_Rendering_Backend on OpenGL2.